# Unable to Compile youtube-dl in Ubuntu from source files

Tags: python, youtube-dl

If I try to run the `sudo make`, I get this error. In my machine I have **Python 3.6.9**, and **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**.

```
mkdir -p zip
for d in youtube_dl youtube_dl/downloader youtube_dl/extractor youtube_dl/postprocessor ; do \
  mkdir -p zip/$d ;\
  cp -pPR $d/*.py zip/$d/ ;\
done
touch -t 200001010101 zip/youtube_dl/*.py zip/youtube_dl/*/*.py
mv zip/youtube_dl/__main__.py zip/
cd zip ; zip -q ../youtube-dl youtube_dl/*.py youtube_dl/*/*.py __main__.py
/bin/sh: 1: zip: not found
Makefile:61: recipe for target 'youtube-dl' failed
make: *** [youtube-dl] Error 127
```

Any advices to how o solve this error? Thanks

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install the `zip` package by:

```sh
sudo apt install zip
```

Then, retry.

Comment: Thank you, i was missing this package and also `pandoc`

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of compiling youtube-dl from source in Ubuntu to get the latest version when you can get the latest stable version by installing the youtube-dl snap package?

```
sudo snap install youtube-dl # launch it with snap run yt-dlp
```

The youtube-dl snap package is updated automatically or can be updated manually with `sudo snap refresh`

Comment: snap is slow. Also, will be more efficient install it from pip with: pip install youtube_dl

Comment: The youtube-dl snap package is just as fast as the youtube-dl .deb package in Ubuntu. snap packages in Ubuntu are often optimized to be faster than they were a few years ago, plus they get automatic updates and no guessing if globally installing a package from PyPI is good advice this time.

Comment: i don't know `snap`, but i wanted to use my modified source code because i added support for one website that i use.